# Reinforcement Learning for classification problems?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am wondering if there is a gym environment for time series classification. I know its probably a bit overkill, but it's mainly for research purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://github.com/harveybc/gym-fx.
The classification task could be whether the closing price is below or over the opening price.